# How to create an accordion in wicket

Tags: wicket, accordion

I am using wicket 1.4.17.I went through quite a few posts on this but couldn't understand it clearly. How can I make an accordion in wicket?

Basically what I am looking for is kind of a table with 1 column and multiple rows where each row can be expanded or collapsed, and each row on expansion shows another table of data.

Answer (score 2):

The following code example should help you get started.
Feel free to ask questions if something seems unclear. Of course you could go even deeper in your DetailPanel (that's why I would suggest that approach)

```
    AbstractRepeater exampleView = new ListView<Object>("exampleView", myList) {


        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<Object> item) {
            //you can use a own panel, fragment, etc to illustrate your detail view here
            //you could also use one WebMarkupContainer for visibility - but I'd assume this will get very messy, very soon
            final DetailPanel detailPanel = new DetailPanel("detailPanel", item.getModel());
            detailPanel.setVisible(false);
            detailPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
            item.add(detailPanel);

            //add AjaxLink to switch between the visibilty of the detailView
            AjaxLink<Void> detailLink = new AjaxLink<Void>("detailLink") {

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    detailPanel.setVisible(!detailPanel.isVisible());
                    target.addComponent(detailPanel);
                }
            };
            item.add(detailLink);

        }
    };
    add(exampleView);
```